# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$user_id in C:\wamp\www\social\includes\class-query.php on line 134

Tags: php, mysql, undefined

Im having this error showing up every time I try to view my time feed. I dont know whats wrong with the code. Can someone help? My code is below. Line 134 will be added first, then the rest of the code

```
public function do_news_feed($user_id) {
                $status_objects = $this->get_status_objects($user_id);

                foreach ( $status_objects as $status ) {?>
                    <div class="status_item">
    Line 134 ----->  <?php $user = $this->load_user_object($status->user_id); ?>
                        <h3><a href="/social/profile-view.php?uid=<?php echo $user->ID; ?>"><?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?></a></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $status->status_content; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
            }
```

The Full code

```
<?php
    require_once('class-db.php');

    if ( !class_exists('QUERY') ) {
        class QUERY {
            public function load_user_object($user_id) {
                global $db;

                $table = 's_users';

                $query = "
                                SELECT * FROM $table
                                WHERE ID = $user_id
                            ";

                $obj = $db->select($query);

                if ( !$obj ) {
                    return "No user found";
                }

                return $obj[0];
            }

            public function load_all_user_objects() {
                global $db;

                $table = 's_users';

                $query = "
                                SELECT * FROM $table
                            ";

                $obj = $db->select($query);

                if ( !$obj ) {
                    return "No user found";
                }

                return $obj;
            }

            public function get_friends($user_id) {
                global $db;

                $table = 's_friends';

                $query = "
                                SELECT ID, friend_id FROM $table
                                WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
                            ";

                $friends = $db->select($query);

                foreach ( $friends as $friend ) {
                    $friend_ids[] = $friend->friend_id;
                }

                return $friend_ids;
            }

            public function get_status_objects($user_id) {
                global $db;

                $table = 's_status';

                $friend_ids = $this->get_friends($user_id);

                if ( !empty ( $friend_ids ) ) {
                    array_push($friend_ids, $user_id);
                } else {
                    $friend_ids = array($user_id);
                }

                $accepted_ids = implode(', ', $friend_ids);

                $query = "
                                SELECT * FROM $table
                                WHERE user_id IN ($accepted_ids)
                                ORDER BY status_time DESC
                            ";

                $status_objects = $db->select($query);

                return $status_objects;
            }

            public function get_message_objects($user_id) {
                global $db;

                $table = 's_messages';

                $query = "
                                SELECT * FROM $table
                                WHERE message_recipient_id = '$user_id'
                            ";

                $messages = $db->select($query);

                return $messages;
            }

            public function do_user_directory() {
                $users = $this->load_all_user_objects();

                foreach ( $users as $user ) { ?>
                    <div class="directory_item">
                        <h3><a href="/social/profile-view.php?uid=<?php echo $user->ID; ?>"><?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?></a></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $user->user_email; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
            }

            public function do_friends_list($friends_array) {
                foreach ( $friends_array as $friend_id ) {
                    $users[] = $this->load_user_object($friend_id);
                }

                foreach ( $users as $user ) { ?>
                    <div class="directory_item">
                        <h3><a href="/social/profile-view.php?uid=<?php echo $user->ID; ?>"><?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?></a></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $user->user_email; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
            }

            public function do_news_feed($user_id) {
                $status_objects = $this->get_status_objects($user_id);

                foreach ( $status_objects as $status ) {?>
                    <div class="status_item">
                        <?php $user = $this->load_user_object($status->user_id); ?>
                        <h3><a href="/social/profile-view.php?uid=<?php echo $user->ID; ?>"><?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?></a></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $status->status_content; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
            }

            public function do_inbox($user_id) {
                $message_objects = $this->get_message_objects($user_id);

                foreach ( $message_objects as $message ) {?>
                    <div class="status_item">
                        <?php $user = $this->load_user_object($message->message_sender_id); ?>
                        <h3>From: <a href="/social/profile-view.php?uid=<?php echo $user->ID; ?>"><?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?></a></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $message->message_subject; ?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $message->message_content; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $query = new QUERY;
?>
```

Comment: do `var_dump($status);` in your foreach loop . and see it have user_id in it or not ??

Comment: so your error is `Undefined property, stdClass:$user_id`, and in your SQL you have `WHERE ID = $user_id`. i wonder what the problem is...

Comment: @AziBaloch when I run the var_dump command it shows this

object(stdClass)[5]
  public 'ID' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'user_ID' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'status_time' => string '2014-04-13 01:03:00' (length=19)
  public 'status_content' => string 'Testing' (length=7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change user_id to user_ID . 
don't forget php is case sensitive

change line `134` to

```
<?php $user = $this->load_user_object($status->user_ID); ?>
```